# View sources of used Java classes in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In visual studio development environment when you use a library if you have the related pdb you can dig into their sources during debug. I wonder is there any way to have this feature when you are developing under Java with IntelliJ Idea IDE? 
I want to see what hibernate do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course, quoting the [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/library.html):

> Libraries may optionally include the source code for the library classes as well as corresponding API documentation. [...] However, it adds the ability to use inline documentation extracted from the source code, and also to view the API documentation right from the IDE.

The documentation doesn't mention you can then debug external libraries, which is obviously also possible.

In order to add sources choose:

- File | Project Structure
- Click Libraries tab
- Pick library and click `+` icon
- Find a JAR file containing sources.

If you are using build tool like [maven](/questions/tagged/maven), IntelliJ will automatically download and attach available source to all libraries, no manual work needed.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I had to add the JDK source files to the project as below.

Go to **Project Structure** -> **SDKs** -> **Sourcepath**

Use the Plus Sign on the right, and provide the path to your $JAVA_HOME/src.zip file.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## `Go to` ➙ `Implementation(s)`

No one suggested the simple route with a context-menu:

1. `import java.util.DesiredClass`
2. *select this import statement*
3. *right click* -> **Go to** -> **Implementation(s)**

Done! The source code of the `DesiredClass` opens in a new tab.

This also works with selected class name in the body of your code.

[image: screenshot of code editor with selected class name for which a context menu item "Go To" > "Implementation(s)" is chosen]

Comment: However, it decompiles java.util.* classes for example; how to attach JDK sources in this case?

Answer (score 4):

`Project Structure` | `Libraries` (or [Module Dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) if libraries are defined there):

[image: Project Structure]

Then in the libries tab click on the plus mark:

[image: Libraries]

Select the source type:

[image: Add source]

Then you have to select the source path and add the wanted libraries finally click apply!

Answer (score 3):

If you use maven, there is a button "Download sourcec" on maven panel.
If you don't, you need to get sources of hibernate first, search on the internet. And then attach them: `File -> Project Structure -> Libraries -> Your hibernate lib -> and attach source`

Answer (score 3):

**Sources for JAVA API**

In Debian, and Ubuntu,

To be able to view sources for Java core API classes, you can install:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk openjdk-11-source
```

`openjdk-*-source` package contains the Java programming language source files
(src.zip) for all classes that make up the Java core API.

Once installed, you should be able to find the installed content under:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/src.zip
```

[image: itellij sdk sourcepath]

Then in IntelliJ, add the JDK, in project settings. If `src.zip` is present within the provided JDK directory, IntelliJ will automatically use it as the sourcepath.

**Sources for external libraries**

If you're using Maven, you can get source files for external dependencies by clicking on the button `'Download Sources and/or Documentation'` provided in [Maven tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-projects-tool-window.html).