# Unable to view complete java source code in IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

Earlier I used Eclipse. Recently I have started using IntelliJ. I found that the IntelliJ equivalent of Eclipse keyboard shortcut <kbd>F3</kbd> (view source) is <kbd>F4</kbd>.

But, when I use that I get the source in the following format.

[image]

It does not show complete source, i.e method implementation is not being shown. I have placed src.zip in the java sdk folder where Java is installed. I have added the src.zip in the project libraries too. In eclipse I can just attach source if it can't find one.

I have seen answers of relevant questions but couldn't follow. So,
**How to attach the Java source in IntelliJ?**

Detailed answer will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to download it. You don't have attached java sources to the project. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781135/view-sources-of-used-java-classes-in-intellij-idea

Comment: If you are using Maven, IntelliJ will give you the option to download the source.

Comment: How to download and attach? Where to attach?

Comment: I've sent a link with the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

1. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>
2. Select SDKs under platform settings.
3. On the right hand side there will be Sourcepath tab
4. Add the downloaded src.zip of java to the sourcepath
5. You can also add the API documentation under the Documentation Path in the same way by adding the downloaded API docs

Answer (score 0):

Source is found in JDK folder, example - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\src.zip. JDK must be downloaded first, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You should attach your source code to your project, get into `Project Structure`, click `Global Libraries`, add the source code jar, usually end with sources.jar, now you can see the source code.

you can see the Sources and JavaDocs under the Classes.

Answer (score 0):

I found I had to add the dependency jars under the model: i.e.

```
project structure -> 
project settings -> 
Modules (select the module where it has problem) -> 
Dependencies (on the right handside pane) -> 
click "+" -> 
library -> then select all the libraries i needed (even though it is available at the root of my sbt project, i had to do this for the module i am interested).
```

also, i kept the library dependency at the build.sbt to be 'compile' scope instead of 'provided'. but sometime you want your dependency to be provided only (such as spark, or hadoop, in this situation)